# Filter the noise from EEG signal

Tags: filter, matlab

I recently recorded the EEG signal with sampling rate of 256Hz.The signal will band passed at 4-64Hz.I need a code to filter the eeg data.Is there any type of filter in matlab is most suitable to filter the artifact or noise from the signal??

Comment: You could use the `butter` and `filter`/`filtfilt` functions, depending on your requirements. You might want a notch filter at 50/60Hz, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply a notch filter at 50 or 60 Hz

Artifacts from eye movements generally have a 2-5 Hz frequency range, So you can apply a high pass filter out there.

Wavelets have a thresholding mechanism to filter out noise (hard and soft thresholding) using wavelet packet decomposition.

Answer (score 2):

in case that your Fs =1000 Hz, use this code to be able to filter the signal and extract the features bands (alpha, beta, ...)

```
S = "your EEG-Data-Row";
waveletFunction = 'db8' OR 'sym8' ;
[C,L] = wavedec(S,8,waveletFunction);
%% Calculation The Coificients Vectors
cD1 = detcoef(C,L,1);                   %NOISY
cD2 = detcoef(C,L,2);                   %NOISY
cD3 = detcoef(C,L,3);                   %NOISY
cD4 = detcoef(C,L,4);                   %NOISY
cD5 = detcoef(C,L,5);                   %GAMA
cD6 = detcoef(C,L,6);                   %BETA
cD7 = detcoef(C,L,7);                   %ALPHA
cD8 = detcoef(C,L,8);                   %THETA
cA8 = appcoef(C,L,waveletFunction,8);   %DELTA
%%%% Calculation the Details Vectors
D1 = wrcoef('d',C,L,waveletFunction,1); %NOISY
D2 = wrcoef('d',C,L,waveletFunction,2); %NOISY
D3 = wrcoef('d',C,L,waveletFunction,3); %NOISY
D4 = wrcoef('d',C,L,waveletFunction,4); %NOISY
D5 = wrcoef('d',C,L,waveletFunction,5); %GAMMA
D6 = wrcoef('d',C,L,waveletFunction,6); %BETA
D7 = wrcoef('d',C,L,waveletFunction,7); %ALPHA
D8 = wrcoef('d',C,L,waveletFunction,8); %THETA
A8 = wrcoef('a',C,L,waveletFunction,8); %DELTA
```

Hope this will help .